# C# : How do I determine the name of the event that was fired and its event/delegate type?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm leveraging on a legacy and unsupported third party API. From what I know, all of its methods return nothing but fires events instead. For a particular method, I have tried hook up event handlers to all the possible events that the method could fire based on the docs but the program didn't run through any of it.

In Visual Studio 2017, is it possible to check which event was fired and also its type (e.g., delegate type)?

**What I've tried**

I've tried looking into the diagnostics tools part of the IDE but nothing seems to mention the name of event that was fired-it only shows the name of the event handler *IF* it was hooked up to an event. But for this scenario, I couldn't hook up an event handler to that event because I don't know the name of the event that was fired by the method *and* its type.

So best if the solution also provides a way to find out the type of that event.

[image: IDE]

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the [Diagnostics Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/) of visual studio should provide you with what you are looking for.

There is this section about [Application insights or UI analysis events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/what-s-new-in-profiling-tools).

it's in Debug, Windows, Show Diagnostic Tools. It should be with other window settings really to be easily found.

Comment: I've looked through the Diagnostics Tool as evidenced in my question above but I'm unable to find the name of the event. Can you show me an example?

Comment: Please do not link to external sites as an answer. Always put your content directly in your answer and only link to support that content.

Answer (score -1):

You can try my [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) extension to see all executed method and event handler names. Then you can probably infer the name of the event that was fired.

Comment: Please do not link to external sites as an answer. Always put your content directly in your answer and only link to support that content.

Comment: For me, this is not preferable because it is just a short term solution i.e., I wouldn't be able to use it after the trial period ends.